# Datatype changes from Int to Float when using group aggregation

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah

I'm trying to use the group aggregation.

I have documents of the following structure in my mongodb:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ddcdc9ab4d8a3a90345508e"), "vehicleId" : "1", "timestamp" : ISODate("2011-05-25T10:40:25.856Z"), "speed" : 1 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ddcdc9ab4d8a3a90345508f"), "vehicleId" : "2", "timestamp" : ISODate("2011-05-25T10:40:26.232Z"), "speed" : 2 }
```

In a test, I want to get the latest speed per vehicleId, i.e. I'm
doing the following:

```
val key = MongoDBObject("vehicleId" -> true)
val cond = MongoDBObject.empty
val initial = MongoDBObject("timestamp" -> 0)

val reduce =
  """function(doc, prev) {
       if (doc.timestamp > prev.timestamp) {
          prev.speed = doc.speed;
          prev.timestamp = doc.timestamp;
       }
     }"""

val groupedSpeed = collection.group(key, cond, initial, reduce)

for (dbObject: DBObject <- groupedSpeed) {
  println(dbObject.toString)
```

The weird thing is that in the collection groupedSpeed, the field
speed is not an Int anymore:

```
{ "vehicleId" : "2" , "timestamp" : { "$date" : "2011-05-25T10:40:49Z"} , "speed" : 2.0}
{ "vehicleId" : "1" , "timestamp" : { "$date" : "2011-05-25T10:40:49Z"} , "speed" : 1.0}
```

Did I miss something? I'm using casbah 2.1.2.

Cheers,
  Christian

**[UPDATE]** Looks like this is normal in javascript and bson, see here: [casbah mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-casbah-users/browse_thread/thread/e28f9bd9a349fa4b)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript represents all numeric values as doubles.

You might want to extend your application logic so whenever a new document is inserted, in a separate collection you also update the max speed for that vehicle, so you never have to do group queries.